# Find a polynomial $p(x)$ so that $p(x)e^{5x}$ is a solution of the second-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a polynomial $p(x)$ so that $p(x)e^{5x}$ is a solution of the second-order differential equation:
$$y''- 10y'+25y=x^2e^{5x}$$,
with the condition that $y(0)=1$ and $y(1)=0$.

So far, I got:
$$\lambda^2-10\lambda+25 = 0$$
$$(\lambda-5)^2=0$$
$$\lambda=5$$

Therefore, the general solution should be:
$$y=c_1e^{5x}+c_2e^{5x}$$

I'm not sure how to use the condition to find the particular solution. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: It's no need to use differential equation theory at all. Just plug $ y = p(x) e^{5x}$ to the equation and see what happen

Comment: The general solution to the associated homogeneous differential equation $y''-10y'+25y=0$ would be $y=c_1e^{5x} + c_2xe^{5x}$. Remember that this is the case for repeated roots.

Answer (score 2):

My simple-minded approach:
just plug in $y = p(x)e^{5x}$.

$\begin{array}\\
y
&= pe^{5x}\\
y'
&= p'e^{5x}+5pe^{5x}\\
&= (p'+5p)e^{5x}\\
y''
&= 5(p'+5p)e^{5x}+(p''+5p')e^{5x}\\
&= (5p'+25p+p''+5p')e^{5x}\\
&= (25p+p''+10p')e^{5x}\\
\text{so}\\
x^2e^{5x}
&=y''- 10y'+25y\\
&=e^{5x}(25p+p''+10p'-10(p'+5p)+25p)\\
&=e^{5x}(25p+p''+10p'-10p'-50p+25p)\\
&=e^{5x}(p'')\\
\text{so}\\
p''
&=x^2\\
\text{or}\\
p
&=\frac1{12}x^4+ax+b\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: +1 Nice Marty. I uppose that $a=b=0$